# macro in other Workbook doesnt get executed

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub Workbook_Open()
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.Run ("'somepath'!ThisWorkbook.OpenMe")
End Sub
```

The Code to execute resides in the ThisWorkbook - Object. The macro - workbook gets opened, but it doesn't get executed. Any ideas?

Comment: Is your macro called `Thisworkbook.OpenMe`? Also read Ron's excellent guide on the application.run event: https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win001.htm

Comment: Yes, it resides in ThisWorkbook, its name is called OpenMe. OpenMe just calls the Workbook_Open routine. I think, because both macros are called from Workbook_Open - routine, there is a mismatch.When I delete the referencing ThisWorkbook., there is error 1004 and the Workbook gets opened. When I write ThisWorkbook into it, Workbook is opened, but macro doesn't start.

Comment: *"OpenMe just calls the Workbook_Open"* I don't see any sense in that because the `Workbook_Open` event runs automatically whet the workbook gets opened. So if you run that again with `OpenMe` it runs twice. So there is something fundamentally wrong in your approach. • Can you explain a bit more and also include the code of `OpenMe`? Providing a [mcve] might also help to improve your question.

Comment: I really need to force that Open - Event. The macro doesn't even start!

Comment: As Pᴇʜ mentions, your should [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52662953/edit) and provide more information. This will help us to help you

Comment: @RWatermelon *"I really need to force that Open - Event. The macro doesn't even start!"* Then please read my comment again and provide the information I asked for (or better even more information) and explain. If you need to force that event you are doing something fundamentally wrong. So in order to help you, we need a full explanation what you are trying to do at all with that approach.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ, Thank you, I misunderstood what i had read previously, your feedback is appreciated. Also, rondebruins' explanation on `Application.Run` was very informative. Again thank you. +

Comment: Oh, I found the problem. In the macro, some line of code prevented the execution of the code. Sorry for any inconveniences.

Comment: Since the issue cannot reproduced anymore I voted to close the question as off-topic.

Comment: I didn't realize, that the macro GOT EXECUTED until some line, where it checks if some value in some cell was set to 1. Took me hours to figure out, that it executes.

Comment: Thank you all for your help, this guide from Ron is very nice

Answer (score 0):

Set some value to 1 in some sheet to execute this thing fully

Comment: enter the calling procedure (Application.Run - Method) into the Module1, too to execute it reliable